# Ruby on rails turn string into date and compare dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Given the following model:

```
class Person

  field :dob, type: String #In the form of YYYY-MM-DD

end
```

How would you write a scope that only gets the people that have :dob values after, say 2000-1-1? Something like what's below:

```
scope :is_child, -> { where(:dob.to_date > "2000-1-1".to_date) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing your date as an ISO8601 formatted string and ISO8601 date strings compare sensibly (i.e. the string comparison matches the corresponding date comparison). That means that you can use simple string operations:

```
scope :is_child, -> { where(:dob.gt => '2000-01-01') }
```

You'd probably want to use a dynamic date based on the current date instead of `2000-01-01` though, otherwise you'll have to update the code every year and that's error prone.

Answer (score -1):

Use Ruby's [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) class to compare dates into your scope.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
scope :is_child, -> {where("? < ?",Date.parse("2001-1-1","%Y-%m-
%d"),Date.parse(self.dob,"%Y-%m-%d"))}
```

Comment: This is Mongoid not ActiveRecord, `where(sql_snippet, ...)` won't work.

Comment: Ups sorry my mystake I didn't realize that you are talking about mongo_id